# Architecturally independent serialization/deserialization of numbers using C

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization, cross-platform

I'm working on small client-server application written on C.

For sending unsigned 32-bit number to remote side used this code:

```
u_int32_t number = 123;
send(client_socket_, &number, 4, CLIENT_SOCKET_FLAGS);
```

For receiving this number on remote side used this code:

```
u_int32_t number;
recv(acceptor, &number, 4, SERVER_DATA_SOCKET_FLAGS);
printf("Number is: %u\n", number);
```

If client and server run on same architecture of processors (`amd64`) - all works fine. 
But if my client app launched on different processor architecture (`mips`) - I getting invalid number on server (bytes order are inverted).

How I can architecturally independent serialize my number in binary format?

**An important feature is the good performance of the binary serializer/deserializer. 
Also the solution should not be tied to a library.**

Comment: since I see the words "socket", "server" and "client" in there why not use [htonl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804418/architecturally-independent-serialization-deserialization-of-numbers-using-c) and [ntohl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804418/architecturally-independent-serialization-deserialization-of-numbers-using-c) ?

Comment: @PeterT, tnx. This works fine too!

Comment: You have to convert the number to the endianess of the _network protocol_. This is what matters. It may or may not be the same as the endianess of the sender and/or receiver CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization

```
static void Ser_uint32_t(uint8_t arr [sizeof(uint32_t)], uint32_t value)
{
    arr[0] = (value >> 24u) & 0xFFu;
    arr[1] = (value >> 16u) & 0xFFu;
    arr[2] = (value >>  8u) & 0xFFu;
    arr[3] = (value >>  0u) & 0xFFu;
}
```

And de-serialization

```
static uint32_t DeSer_uint32_t(const uint8_t arr [sizeof(uint32_t)])
{
    uint32_t x = 0;
    x |= (uint32_t)(arr[0]) << 24u;
    x |= (uint32_t)(arr[1]) << 16u;
    x |= (uint32_t)(arr[2]) <<  8u;
    x |= (uint32_t)(arr[3]) <<  0u;

    return x;
}
```

Depending on the endianness you want you can correct the posted functions

Comment: Minor nitpick: You should declare `const unsigned char **p`, since array is not modified on deserialization.

Comment: Minor nitpick: A better alternative might be to use array syntax. `static uint32_t DeSer_uint32_t(const uint8_t arr [sizeof(uint32_t)])` since that makes the code much more readable: `x |= (uint32_t)arr[0] << 24u;`. I would also leave the `*p += 4` iteration to the caller.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it is more readable as you proposed. And about increment: yes, can avoid passing 4 bytes and returning accessing the passed buffer out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use hexadecimal encoding.
Eg: `0xDEADBEEF` will literally be send as: `<stx>DEADBEEF<etx>`.

This method has the advantage of not losing the ability to use [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29).
This method has the disadvantage that each number byte is doubled.

Conversion is easy, you can use a lookup table after masking a nibble.
It's a bit like using something like json, but more lightweight in execution.

Comment: This method also has the more significant disadvantage that the data will sometimes get sent as `EFBEADDE`... There is CPU endianess and there is also network protocol endianess.

Comment: @Lundin, not with snprintf. Also a byte stream is not supposed to be changed by the platform endian. It would be a block based interface if the endian would matter there.

Comment: There's no snprintf in your answer. Anyway, converting to ASCII might not be the best idea anyway since it gives extra overhead.